# Can anyone provide the logic why it is returning true?

Tags: c++, if-statement

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    float f =9.58;
    if(f<9.58)
    {
        cout<<"T";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"F";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As per the logic, 9.58 is equal to 9.58 so it should return false but it is returning true.

Comment: You should be careful with your literals `float f = 9.58f` and `if (f < 9.58f)`

Comment: I haven't tried it, but my intuition is that you have a low-precision float compared to a high-precision double.

Comment: Try `0.5` or `0.25` instead of `9.58`.  If the return value is `false`, then you will get a taste of binary floating point math, and what can be represented exactly in binary floating point.

Comment: @Wyck I did and with 9.58f in both places it returns false as expected.

Comment: Compare the binary representation of [float](https://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=057046053056) to [double](https://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=057046053056) and I imagine when the float gets promoted to double for comparison, it can't correctly estimate all those missing bits (they're probably zero-filled, which is why the float is less than the double).

Comment: Its precision loss, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/why-floating-point-numbers-may-lose-precision?view=msvc-160 explains why comparing floats directly is not a good idea.

Comment: you should also be able to see this by doing ``cout.precision(32);std::cout << f << std::endl;`` and see that 9.58 is actually stored as a value less than 9.58.